# In KnockoutJS the with binding is clearing my DOM

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a rather complex ViewModel with the following Sub-ViewModels:

```
define('budgetCalculatorViewModel',
  ['knockout', 'jquery', 'dependantsBankResidenceViewModel', 'employmentViewModel', 'incomeViewModel', 'expenditureViewModel', 'priorityDebtViewModel', 'courtOrderCreditDebtContainerViewModel', 'frequencyValues'],
  function (ko, $, dependantsBankResidenceViewModel, employmentViewModel, incomeViewModel, expenditureViewModel, priorityDebtViewModel, courtOrderCreditDebtContainerViewModel, frequencyValues) {
    function budgetCalculatorViewModel() {
      var self = this;

      self.employment = new employmentViewModel();
      self.dependants = new dependantsBankResidenceViewModel();
      self.income = new incomeViewModel();
      self.expenditure = new expenditureViewModel();
      self.priorityDebts = new priorityDebtViewModel();
      self.courtOrders = new courtOrderCreditDebtContainerViewModel();
      self.frequencyValues = ko.observableArray(frequencyValues);
      self.index = ko.observable(0);
    }

    return budgetCalculatorViewModel;
  });
```

The HTML that will be bound to all those ViewModels sits in one View file (`.cshtml` as I'm working in ASP.Net MVC).

In my View, I am doing this:

```
<div class="tab-content transparent">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 block employment" data-bind="with: self.employment">
        <div class="block-title">
          <h3>Your <strong>Employment</strong></h3>
          <hr />
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: self.isEmployed" /> Are you employed?
          </label>
        </div>

        <!-- other markup taken off -->

      </div><!-- .col-md-12 .block .employment -->
    </div><!-- .row -->
  </div><!-- .tab-pane -->
</div><!-- .tab-content -->
```

But this isn't working! When the page loads in Chrome, everything after the bind is gone missing from the DOM! Here's a screenshot!

[image: no content]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're ultimately binding to an instance of `budgetCalculatorViewModel`, you shouldn't be using `with: self.employment`, it should just be `with: employment`:

```
<div class="col-md-12 block employment" data-bind="with: employment">
```

In your model, `self` was referring to the `budgetCalculatorViewModel` instance, whereas in the binding knockout will be looking for a property called `self` within the instance, which doesn't exist.  [The documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) notes that:

> The `with` binding will dynamically add or remove descendant elements depending on whether the associated value is `null`/`undefined` or not

and since `self.employment` doesn't exist, it removes all the inner elements.

Comment: I would have thought `self.employment` and `employment` would have meant the same thing, but I guess I was wrong :) Thanks, you were right! I'll mark as answer in 5 minutes